# Building an CSP channel in Scala.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala.js

flowwers :-),

I try to build a one item `CSP` channel to compile with `Scala.JS`:

```
class Channel[T]() {
  private var promise: Promise[T] = Promise[T]()

  /** Auxiliary constructor
  * Binds a continuation  with the "write" in casu update()
  * @param cont
  */
  def this(cont: (T => Unit) => Unit) {
    this
    cont(update)
  }

  /** Channels' "Write" or "put" function, called by an assigned to the instance(). */
  def update(t: T): Unit = if (!promise.isCompleted) promise.success(t)
  }

  /** Channels' "Read" or "get" function, called by referring to the instance(). */
  def apply(): Future[T] = {
    promise = Promise[T]()
    promise.future
  }
```

usage, (companion object not shown with `apply() = new Channel( ... methods )`):

```
val mouseChannel = new Channel[org.scalajs.dom.raw.MouseEvent](org.scalajs.dom.document.onmousemove = _)

...
async{ // Blocking await block
...
val event: org.scalajs.dom.raw.MouseEvent= await(mouseChannel())
...
}
```

or

```
val instance = new Channel[T]
jQuery("button01").click({ () => instance() = null /*calling update() method */ })

...

async{
...
  await(instance()) // Waiting on a key click by calling apply()
...
}
```

And it works! The only thing is, it does not block the sender. The true `CSP` religion says blocking write to give it a "synchronized handshake". Also preventing the loss of data and even giving it a "back-pressure".

I tried several things but nothing worked. Remember on a `JS` -platform not all `JVM` possibilities are available e.g. `Object.wait` and `scala.concurrent.Await`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm.  If bocking is crucial, then this might not be the right approach -- blocking is intentionally impossible, because it doesn't exist on the underlying platform...

Comment: @Justin What you think of blocking in an Async block? It's done before.

Comment: I'm always leery of blocking - comes from years of Akka - but in this case it just plain isn't possible, since blocking can't be done in Scala.js...